# Leading illegal characters after XSLT transformation

Tags: c#, asp.net, xslt

After an XSLT transformation I keep getting leading question marks that (seem to) have to do with character encoding, but I can't get rid of them. I have tried all different encodings, but it didn't help. I'm stuck with an in-memory xml source, as I serialize objects.

This is my code (as short as possible to reproduce the problem)

```
var xd = new XmlDocument();
xd.LoadXml(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?><Test><AAA>AAA</AAA></Test>");

var xslt = new System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform();
xslt.Load(Server.MapPath("/Transformations/Test.xslt"));

using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    xslt.Transform(xd, null, ms);
    ms.Position = 1;

    using (var sr = new StreamReader(ms, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, true))
    {
        string s = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

And this is the XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:output method="text"  indent="no"/>
    <xsl:template match="Test">
        BBB<xsl:value-of select="AAA" />CCC
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Produces:

```
��\r\n\t\tBBBAAACCC\r\n\t
```

It's probably very simple, but I can't figure it out...

Regards,

Heras

Comment: Maybe it's the byte order mark (BOM) which is used to give a hint in which encoding a text file is saved. (Visual Studio saves most of its text files like `.cs` in UTF-8 with BOM by default.) [See also here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_Order_Mark)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the `ms.Position` to 0 instead of 1

C# arrays are zero indexed.

Comment: Although the stream is backed by an array, that's an implementation detail. I'd rather say that [`Stream.Position`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.position.aspx) is zero based.

Comment: I feel rather silly now. This solved it... I was so focussed on character encoding, that I didn't take notice... Thanks!!!